# How to create lauch.json to start glsl canvas extension when pressing F5?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, glsl

I installed the [vscode-glsl-canvas](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=circledev.glsl-canvas) extension to visualize shaders in VSCode. Now I would like to run the shader = open the extension/canvas by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then selecting the command. The command executed is apparently the following:

```
@command:glsl-canvas.showGlslCanvas
```

How do I create a `launch.json` file in the folder to execute this command when pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>?